# Perl complex regex search-and-replace with nested expressions

Tags: regex, perl, replace

I have Perl code as follows (excerpted from a longer code):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash_all_dffs = (d6 => "1", d7 => "1", d8 => "1", d9 => "1");
#print %hash_all_dffs;

my $search = join( "|", map {quotemeta} keys %hash_all_dffs);
$search = qr/\b($search)\b/;
#print $search;

# read all lines at once
$/ = "";

# read inline text and process
while (<DATA>) {
        # search for match pattern, do replacement
        $_ =~ s/(?:module.*?\(.*?\)\s*;)(*SKIP)(*F)|\breg\b\s*(\[\s*\d+\s*\:\s*\d+\s*\])?(\s*\b$search\b\s*,)*?\s*\b$search\b\s*;
               / my $tmp4  =  $&;
                 my $tmp50 =  $&;
                 my $tmp51 =  $&;
                 my $tmp52 =  $&;
                 $tmp4  =~ s,\n,\n\/\/,gs;
                 $tmp50 =~ s,($search),$2_tmr0,gs;
                 $tmp51 =~ s,($search),$2_tmr1,gs;
                 $tmp52 =~ s,($search),$2_tmr2,gs;
                 "\/\/".$tmp4."\n".$tmp50."\n".$tmp51."\n".$tmp52."\n"
               /gesx;
        print;
        }

__DATA__
reg     [1:0]   d7 ,
                d8 ;
```

Output is following text:

```
//reg     [1:0]   d7 ,
//                d8 ;
reg     [1:0]   d7_tmr0 ,
                d8_tmr0 ;
reg     [1:0]   d7_tmr1 ,
                d8_tmr1 ;
reg     [1:0]   d7_tmr2 ,
                d8_tmr2 ;
```

So far so good (maybe ugly, though >_<).

**My intention:** 
I wanna add some extra text at the end of the output, and the new stuff is like (Verilog TMR redundancy code):

```
assign d7_tmrvote = (d7_tmr0 & d7_tmr1) | (d7_tmr0 & d7_tmr2) | (d7_tmr1 & d7_tmr2);
assign d8_tmrvote = (d8_tmr0 & d8_tmr1) | (d8_tmr0 & d8_tmr2) | (d8_tmr1 & d8_tmr2);
```

If there is just one `reg` declared in the original text (ie. there's only `d7` or only `d8`), it's rather simple (still ugly, though) to do what I intend.

**Problem:** However, the problem that hassles me is that there might be one, or two, or more of `reg` declared, ie. there might be `d7` and `d8` (shown in my code), or might be (`d7`, `d8`, `d9`, `d10`, `d11` ....). Seems I'll have to store them into some sort of temporary variable to help with the replacement, but I don't know how to it in `s///gsex` regex. I hope I can do this without great overhaul to the original code.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks in advance~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually managed to do it on my own; the Perl code is kind of ugly, though:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash_all_dffs = (d6 => "1", d7 => "1", d8 => "1", d9 => "1");
#print %hash_all_dffs;

my $search = join( "|", map {quotemeta} keys %hash_all_dffs);
$search = qr/\b($search)\b/;
#print $search;

# read all lines at once
$/ = "";

# read inline text and process
while (<DATA>) {
        # search for match pattern, do replacement
        $_ =~ s/(?:module.*?\(.*?\)\s*;)(*SKIP)(*F)|\breg\b\s*(\[\s*\d+\s*\:\s*\d+\s*\])?(\s*\b$search\b\s*,)*?\s*\b$search\b\s*;
               / my $tmp4  =  $&;
                 my $tmp50 =  $&;
                 my $tmp51 =  $&;
                 my $tmp52 =  $&;
                 my $tmp6  =  $&;
                 my $tmp9 ;
                 $tmp4  =~ s,\n,\n\/\/,gs;
                 $tmp50 =~ s,($search),$2_tmr0,gs;
                 $tmp51 =~ s,($search),$2_tmr1,gs;
                 $tmp52 =~ s,($search),$2_tmr2,gs;
                 my @list_tmr_reg = ( $tmp6  =~ m,$search,gs );
                 foreach(0..$#list_tmr_reg) {
                        my $tmp7 = $list_tmr_reg[$_];
                        my $tmp8 = "${tmp7}_vote = ( ${tmp7}_tmr0 & ${tmp7}_tmr1 ) | ( ${tmp7}_tmr0 & ${tmp7}_tmr1 ) | ( ${tmp7}_tmr0 & ${tmp7}_tmr1 );";
                        $tmp9 = $tmp9.$tmp8;
                        }
                 "\/\/".$tmp4."\n".$tmp50."\n".$tmp51."\n".$tmp52."\n".$tmp9
               /gesx;
        print;
        }

__DATA__
reg     [1:0]   d7 ,
                d8 ;
```

Thanks for viewing ;-)